# Getting wrong output in parallel code in OpenCL

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I am a newbie in parallel programming. I am trying my hands on **PrefixSum** problem in OpenCL. But i am getting wrong output. So while debugging i changed my kernel to perform some simple operation. I am working on Windows8 64 bit machine with AMD GPU.

Here is my kernel code -

```
__kernel void add(__global float *input, __global float *output, __global float *temp)
{
    int thid = get_global_id(0);
    int pout = 0;
    int pin = 1;
    temp[pin*8 + thid] = input[thid];
    temp[pout*8 + thid] = input[thid];
    pout = 1-pout;
    pin = 1-pout; 
    int offset = 1;

    if(thid >= offset) { 
        temp[pout*8 + thid] =temp[pout*8 + thid] + temp[pin*8 + thid - offset];
    } else {
       temp[pout*8 + thid] = temp[pin*8 + thid];
    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    output[thid] =  temp[pout*8 + thid];
}
```

And this is my host code -

```
    int main(void)
{
cl_context context;
cl_context_properties properties[3];
cl_kernel kernel;
cl_command_queue command_queue;
cl_program program;
cl_int err;
cl_uint num_of_platforms=0;
cl_platform_id platform_id;
cl_device_id device_id;
cl_uint num_of_devices=0;  
cl_mem inputA,inputB, output;
outfile.open("shubham.txt");
size_t global=8;

float inputDataA[DATA_SIZE]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
float results[DATA_SIZE]={0};
float inputDataB[16] = {0};
float shubh[16] = {0};
int i;//,j;

//cl_int infoSize = 10000;
//size_t infoSize;
//char *info;
// retreive a list of platforms avaible
//cl_int p = ;


if(clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &num_of_platforms) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Unable to get platform id\n");
    return 1;
}


// try to get a supported GPU device
if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, &num_of_devices) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
//  printf("shbham");
printf("Unable to get device_id\n");
return 1;
}

// context properties list - must be terminated with 0
properties[0]= CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM;
properties[1]= (cl_context_properties) platform_id;
properties[2]= 0;

// create a context with the GPU device
context = clCreateContext(properties,1,&device_id,NULL,NULL,&err);

// create command queue using the context and device
command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);

// create a program from the kernel source code
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,(const char **) &ProgramSource, NULL, &err);

// compile the program
if (clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
printf("Error building program\n");
return 1;
}

// specify which kernel from the program to execute
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "add", &err);

// create buffers for the input and ouput

inputA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, NULL);
inputB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * 16, NULL, NULL);
output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, NULL, NULL);

// load data into the input buffer
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputA, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, inputDataA, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputB, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * 16, inputDataB, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * DATA_SIZE, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);

// set the argument list for the kernel command
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputA);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputB);

// enqueue the kernel command for execution
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clFinish(command_queue);

// copy the results from out of the output buffer
clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) *DATA_SIZE, results, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, inputB, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) *16, shubh, 0, NULL, NULL);

// print the results
printf("output: ");

for(i=0;i<DATA_SIZE; i++)
{
printf("%f ",results[i]);
outfile << results[i] << endl;
}
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
outfile << shubh[i] <<" ";
}
// cleanup - release OpenCL resources
clReleaseMemObject(inputA);
clReleaseMemObject(inputB);
clReleaseMemObject(output);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
clReleaseContext(context);
return 0;
}
```

I am running this code with 8 work items. The input is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and the expected output should be [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15] but every time i run my code i am getting different output like [1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15]. It seems some **thid** are not updating its index in temp in the "if" condition.

If the problem is because of not using atomic_add function while adding in "if" condition then what should be the syntax to change it to an atomic one, i have tried by myself but getting error while compiling.

Or, if there is any other problem then please help me in correcting it.

PS. I am running my code with DEVICE_TYPE_CPU and it is showing error while using DEVICE_TYPE_GPU. I hope it is not the cause of the problem.

Please help

Comment: Unless you are using a single work group, the barrier is not doing what you expect it to do. Does the kernel work properly when you use only 1 group of 8 items?

Comment: What are the contents of input? If we knew a little more about your starting data, it would be easier to help debug your situation.

Comment: @mfa i am passing global work size as 8 and local work size as NULL..and yes i have checked it is working properly for 1 group of 8 items

Comment: @BruceDean my bad..input is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: @ShubhamGupta if you specify NULL for the local work group size you let the implementation decide. I assume the AMD implementation is choosing 1 as local workgroup size and you have 8 workgroups of size 1. So you have 8 threads performing data races on your temp array. It is global memory and so its shared among workgroups. the barriers does not help here because you cannot synchronize across workgroups in OpenCL but you need such a synchronization. This will also explain why your code is working correctly if you specify a local worgroup size of 8. Then you have 1 worgroup and barrier can sync

Comment: @MichaelHaidl yes, i think you are correct. and please correct me i have to then change my temp array in kernel to __ local and then i have to use get_local_id and barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)???

Comment: yes, local memory is distinct for each workgroup. However, if you just have 1 workitem inside your workgroup you are unable to prefetch your data in the way you are trying to, because you cannot access local memory from a different workgroup. I will move my comment to my answer.

Comment: You're not expecting global work item synchronization using `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)`, are you? Because there is no global work item synchronization; only work group synchronization. If you want global synchronization use multiple kernels.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** If you specify NULL for the local work group size you let the implementation decide. I assume the AMD implementation is choosing 1 as local workgroup size and you have 8 workgroups of size 1. So you have 8 threads performing data races on your temp array. It is global memory and so its shared among workgroups. the barriers does not help here because you cannot synchronize across workgroups in OpenCL but you need such a synchronization. This will also explain why your code is working correctly if you specify a local worgroup size of 8. Then you have 1 workgroup and barrier can synchronize your threads.

---

Ok lets look at your kernel:

```
__kernel void add(__global float *input, __global float *output, __global float *temp)
{
    int thid = get_global_id(0);
    int pout = 0;
    int pin = 1;
    temp[pin*8 + thid] = input[thid];
    temp[pout*8 + thid] = input[thid];
    pout = 1-pout;
    pin = 1-pout; 
    int offset = 1;

    if(thid >= offset) { 
        temp[pout*8 + thid] =temp[pout*8 + thid] + temp[pin*8 + thid - offset];
    } else {
       temp[pout*8 + thid] = temp[pin*8 + thid];
    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    output[thid] =  temp[pout*8 + thid];
}
```

At first I would remove the extra storage since it just copies the data twice it's a performance killer and might be your problem as well. (I don't know the hardware you are running the kernel on, and if there is something like implicit warp synchronization as on Nvidia GPUs). The problem here (from parallel programming point of view) is a simple race condition. Your threads have not written to temp before other threads us the data. Two solutions: a) get rid of temp, b) put a barrier before your if statement. However, in OpenCL a barrier can only synchronize threads in the same workgroup so this kernel could bring up the same problem if you are using more than one workgroup.

Since you are just reading from input and writing to output you don't need temp:

```
__kernel void add(__global float *input, __global float *output, __global float *temp)
{
    int thid = get_global_id(0);
    int offset = 1;

    if(thid >= offset) { 
       output[thid] = input[thid] + input[thid - offset];
    } else {
       output[thid] = input[thid];
    }
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: @ Micheal Haidi As i said i was trying prefixsum problem and was getting wrong output so i reduced my code to above one and found that some "thid" are not performing their work. I have tried putting a barrier before the "if" statement but it is also serving wrong output

Comment: @ShubhamGupta wrong input? the kernel you showed should actually do what you think it should do

Comment: @micheal haidi temp initially contains nothing, the purpose of using it was to use it as a local memory to reduce time. There is one more thing  i am running my code on DEVICE_TYPE_CPU because on DEVICE_TYPE_GPU it is showing error while building.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta yes I see that, maybe your input array is wrong. what  error do you see when you built it for GPU?

Comment: @michealhaidi i think there is no problem with input array, i am properly writing it to buffer and then passing it. and while running it on GPU it shows that it is not able to get device id

Comment: what do you see if you'r using my kernel? if it shows the right output please provide more of your code the problem may related to the host part of your code and not the kernel code

Comment: @michealhaidi Your code is giving correct output. and i am going to edit my post with the host code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67194/discussion-between-shubham-gupta-and-michael-haidl).